# Running VBoxManage from guest vm?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a need to disable host time syncing selectively on a vagrant/virtualbox vm.  I can do that without issue on the host machine like so:

```
$ VBoxManage setextradata <name> \
> "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" "1"
```

The issue is that I only need to disable syncing while some work is done in the guest vm. Specifically, a unit test job needs to be able to toggle the `GetHostTimeDisabled` value programmatically, effectively giving full control of the vm system time to the test job.

I've considered running the VBoxManage command over ssh from within the unit test job but that brings up additional difficulty. Like, for example, setting up passwordless login to my local machine as the vagrant user.

I have ssh agent forwarding enabled for the vm and it's confirmed working. Unless anyone has suggestions for a "better" way, I'd appreciated some help figuring out how to ssh back to the host machine (OSX) from the vm (ubuntu linux) as the vagrant user. Ideally I'd like it to work the same for all users of the vagrant. Maybe using the forwarded agent somehow?

Perhaps there's a way to manipulate VBoxService on the guest to temporarily disable time sync?

Comment: I know the OP found an answer, but I wonder if you could do this with shared folders? You could set up a symlink from VBoxManage.exe to the host version of the shared folder, then run it from there on the guest. Once they figure out what they want to do with symlinks in the guest, maybe you could symlink from there to somewhere else. I wonder what kinds of permissions messes this would set up, especially if you try to change properties of that same guest? *shudder*

Comment: OK, I tried my crazy `shared folders idea, but it didn't work, I think because my host OS is different from my guest OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this using ssh to run the VBoxManage command on the host machine.

1. Enable ssh forwarding in your Vagrantfile

   - e.g., `config.ssh.forward_agent = true`
2. Enable yourself to ssh to yourself as yourself ;)

   - In other words, copy your own public key to your own authorized_keys file
   - e.g., `$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. Set the VM to ssh as you by default (instead of the vagrant user)

   - e.g., via the shell provisioner in your Vagrantfile:

     ```
       require 'etc'
       username = Etc.getlogin
       config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo \"Host *\n  User #{username}\" > /home/vagrant/.ssh/config"
     ```
4. Freely ssh back to the host like so: (the default NAT IP of the host is 10.0.2.2)

   ```
   $ ssh 10.0.2.2 'hostname'
   $ ssh 10.0.2.2 'VBoxManage setextradata <your vm name> \
     "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" "1"'
   $ echo "GetHostTimeDisabled is now " && \
     ssh 10.0.2.2 'VBoxManage getextradata <your vm name> \
     "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled"'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have found an answer, but I've thought of a different way.

VirtualBox has a concept called "shared folders". This means that you can set up a folder on the host that will be available for mounting on the guest, and which stays the same between host & guest, meaning you can share data while the guest is running. You can even have it automatically mounted, in which case it will be mounted as `/media/<folder>`. Then, you can symlink it to wherever you want.

For my idea, you would put `VBoxManage.exe` into the shared folder from the host, then call it from wherever you put it in the guest, and possibly put it in your PATH. Then you'd call

```
$ /path/to/VBoxManage setextradata <guest name> \
> "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" "1"
```

from your script or whatever.

I just tried this, and it didn't work, but I have a feeling that was because my host & guest are different OS's, specifically Windows & Linux, respectively. I suspect calling `dos2unix` on `VBoxManage.exe` might work, but I'm afraid to try it because it might break VirtualBox. It might work better for you, though.

Comment: This most likely didn't work because you're running VBoxManage from inside your guest, rather than your host. It will get different memory and will be executed from inside the guest; the guest will be all it sees. It'd be like you mounted an FTP share in your guest and you're executing a .exe from the FTP share directly, it won't change things on the FTP server, it will change things on your system. I suspect it'd be easier to use a shared folder and have a cronjob scan for changes to the directory, then execute actions based on that; however, it wouldnt be able to run in the scope of the host